# vb6 to vb.net : Array of controls

Tags: vb.net, vb6

In vb6 you could create a an array of the same control and you could add and remove them dynamically, also you could keep count.

How do you do something similar in vb.net ?

Comment: There is not anything exactly like that.  `Private myList As New List(Of Button)` is close, but you already can get at them by name etc in the controls collection

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished easily with a `List`

```
 Dim controlList As List(Of Control)
    controlList.Add(New Button())
    controlList.Add(New TextBox())
    controlList.Add(New ListView())
    controlList.Add(New Label())
    controlList.Add(New ComboBox())
```

In my example I used the base `Control` object as the `List` type to portray the ability to populate any control into a list but this can be any specific control type you'd like. `Button`, `TextBox`, `Label`, etc.

To get a count of the controls in the list you can use the `List` function `.Count()`

If an array is required for your use case you can use the `List` function `.ToArray()`